# I don't understand why the number of object that was garbage collected is 4

Tags: java

There was a problem in our practice test that I did not quite understand. The problem is, "How many object/s will be garbage collected if we put arr2d = null in line 36.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFz4D.png)
The answer was 4, and I am confuse on how that became the answer to the question.

I was unable to answer the question so I have no clue where to start.

Comment: don't add links to images with code. Post your code formatted in your question

Comment: Hy, welcome to Stack Overflow, please [don't upload text, table or error message as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). 
Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. 
Also see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is quite Easy. You are creating a Array which contains 3 Arrays.
This will result in a total of 4 Arrays 1 big Array and 3 Arrays in the big Array.

`int` is a primitive Datatype and doesnt need to be collected by the Garbage Cleaner. Which means that it has to remove 4 Elements.